# React Native crash IllegalArgumentException Could not convert class android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a React Native chat / messenger app. In order to get the intent the app was launched with (say with a share intent), I am overriding the createReactActivityDelegate method in MainActivity.java

However, this is causing the app to crash repeatably with the following exceptions:

```
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester, PID: 6977
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert class    
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle(Unknown Source:152)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.M.c(Unknown Source:40)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.M.b(Unknown Source:87)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.M.a(Unknown Source:0)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.G.run(Unknown Source:6)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
03-30 10:30:50.165  6977  7026 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

AND

```
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.heloprotocol.helo.chat.app.rn.notificationtester, PID: 29352
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert class android.os.BinderProxy
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle(Unknown Source:152)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.M.c(Unknown Source:40)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.M.b(Unknown Source:87)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.M.a(Unknown Source:0)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at d.f.n.G.run(Unknown Source:6)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
03-31 12:58:53.844 29352 29396 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I can see the following exception in debug mode:

```
2020-03-16 17:26:05.214 31063-31063/com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester, PID: 31063
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester/com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert class android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert class android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromBundle(Arguments.java:302)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1063)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootView(ReactInstanceManager.java:748)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.attachToReactInstanceManager(ReactRootView.java:568)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:399)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.startReactApplication(ReactRootView.java:363)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.loadApp(ReactDelegate.java:102)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.loadApp(ReactActivityDelegate.java:88)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onCreate(ReactActivityDelegate.java:83)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:44)
        at com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-03-16 17:26:05.249 31063-31458/com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
2020-03-16 17:26:05.258 31063-31063/com.heloprotocol.helo.app.rn.notificationtester I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31063 SIG: 9
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28461